# Extend a class in an existing architecture?

Tags: c++, inheritance, architecture, game-engine

The question is only relevant for typed programming languages, dynamic solutions aren't satisfying. Let's assume that the language is C++.

Example architecture:

```
- DisplayObject (base class)
-- Container (derived from DisplayObject)
-- Sprite (derived from DisplayObject)
```

So I have a game engine in my hands and it only has X and Y coordinates. Let's say I want to add a Z coordinate. To do this, I'd have to modify the base class `DisplayObject`. Because if I simply derive from it to add the Z-axis functionality, it would make it impossible to use classes `Container` and `Sprite` in my code without casting them to my new `DisplayObject`.

The question is, how to solve this without using casting?
There are dozens of classes derived from `DisplayObject`, so modifying them all one by one would look very weird.
I was also suggested delegation, but I don't see how to apply it here.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please take [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help). You might have more luck asking this on [Software Engineering](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Hello @RawN, thanks for the suggestion, I'll ask that there then.

Comment: Hm.. Why can't you modify your base class? In any case change from 2-d to 3-d looks groundbreaking. It is a good chance that you will have to rewrite almost everything.

Comment: How to "modify the base class" in a typed language? In a dynamic language like javascript you can just write `DisplayObject.prototype.myFunc = function(){...}` and be done. But you can't do `DisplayObject::myFunc(){...}` in a typed programming language, it just won't compile because you didn't declare the function in the class, you only wrote the implementation of it.

Comment: Assuming the `DisplayObject` Class is a generic class for all objects to be drawn to the screen (e.g. sprite, assets, e.t.c...), I would just add a `z-pos` variable to this class, and refactor the functions to use this. You will then want to implement a `GameScreen` class that takes these co-ordinates in 3D space and translates these to a 2D co-ordinate on the screen (using Matrix math).